# WP 7.5 - What could cause ListBox scroll bars to stay visible?

Tags: listbox, scrollbar, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

The Windows Phone 7 default is for scroll bars to display only when a user is scrolling.  In my app they're staying present constantly, and I verified that ScrollViewer visibility properties are not being set anywhere.  Is there anything else that can cause the scroll bars to display permanently?

Comment: This post may be helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/8924ca9b-2052-4a77-b0ab-49e69482cb4f

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the problem on my emulator even..so try this ..take a xaml file n use this code..

```
  <Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle1" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" Background="DarkGray"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle1" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                              Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}" >
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Suppose u r using the scrollviewer in list box u should follow this code:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="AppList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="30" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItem}" Height="525" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```